# How to divide HTML found in .cshtml files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I've got an ASP.NET Core MVC Web App, and one of my Views has too much HTML, causing it to look messy and difficult to find stuff, is there a way to extract some of the HTML (for example a certain div) to a different .cshtml file that I can then include in the View?

Comment: You can try to use Partial View.

Comment: @YiyiYou i'll look into that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [partial view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0) sample:

Shared/partial1.cshtml:

```
<h1>partial1</h1>
```

Test.cshtml:

```
<partial name="partial1" />
```

Or:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("partial1.cshtml")
```

result:

[image]

You can also use View Component,here is an official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0).